# New edit to same answer is not showing?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-summary

I have edited my 5 minutes old answer as shown below, but it is showing as answered 5 minutes ago. It's not showing as `edited now` as it showed some days ago when I made this kind of changes.
[image: screenshot of edited post]

Has this feature been abandoned?

Because now on Stack Overflow it is not displaying anything when a user edits his own answer. It
means the user who posted the question will not be informed that the old answer is modified after seeing the new answer and that's not right. It's like cheating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 5 minute grace period.

If you edit your answer up to 5 minutes after posting it, the edit will not be shown.

This allows fixing typos and other minor mistakes without cluttering the revision history.

Similarly, if you edit some post now and up to 5 minutes later, only a single edit will show up in the revision history, for the same reasons.

Every other edit **will** be registered.

Comment: `s/fire/for/` quickly, or it will be registered

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry to say but i am not getting your point.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees Dennis has a typo, "fire the same reasons". I urged him to substitute "fire" with "for" to correct it.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Too late. Well, if you have two typos in a four-letter-word, it deserves to get registered...